# Problem with jQuery add() issue

Tags: jquery

I have a quick question. My brain is fried and I cannot think :(.

Why the following code is not adding  tag to MyDivClass:

```
$("div.MyDivClass").add("<a href='' id='test'><span></span></a>");
$("div.MyDivClass a#test").attr("href","www.test.com");
$("div.MyDivClass a#test span").html("text1");
```

Comment: I solved the problem by changing add to append.

What is the problem with using add()? Do I just need to specify "a" instead of the whole tag?

Comment: see: http://api.jquery.com/add/ where it says: "The following will not save the added elements, because the .add() method creates a new set and leaves the original set in pdiv unchanged"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [add()](http://api.jquery.com/add/) method only adds the matched elements to the current jQuery object. It does not add new elements to the DOM.

Use [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) instead:

```
$("div.MyDivClass").append("<a href='' id='test'><span></span></a>");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think [.add](http://api.jquery.com/add/) only works with a tag like

```
$("div.MyDivClass").add('a');
```

Try [.html](http://api.jquery.com/html/) instead

```
$("div.MyDivClass").html("<a href='' id='test'><span></span></a>");
```

Comment: Yeah, using html() will remove the other elements present in that div.

Comment: ok... so just keep it ;)
`var d = $("div.MyDivClass");
d.html( d.html() + "<a href='' id='test'><span></span></a>");`

Answer (score 0):

The [`add` method](http://api.jquery.com/add/) adds an element to the set of elements contained in a jQuery object.

It doesn't actually modify the DOM.

For example:

```
var links = $('a');
var linksAndBolds = links.add($('b'));

linksAndBolds.css("color", "pink");
```

To append an element to the DOM tree inside a jQuery onject, call `append`.